# Finding all values that occurs odd number of times in huge list of positive integers

Tags: list, hash

I came across this question from a colleague.

Q: Given a huge list (say some thousands)of positive integers & has many values repeating in the list, how to find those values occurring odd number of times?
Like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1...
Here,
1 occrus 8 times
2 occurs 7 times (must be listed in output)
3 occurs 6 times
4 occurs 5 times (must be listed in output)

& so on... (the above set of values is only for explaining the problem but really there would be any positive numbers in the list in any order).

Originally we were looking at deriving a logic (to be based on c).

I suggested the following,

1. Using a hash table and the values from the list as an index/key to the table, keep updating the count in the corresponding index every time when the value is encountered while walking through the list; however, how to decide on the size of the hash table?? I couldn't say it surely though it might require Hashtable as big as the list.
2. Once the list is walked through & the hash table is populated (with the 'count' number of occurrences for each values/indices), only way to find/list the odd number of times occurring value is to walk through the table & find it out? Is that's the only way to do?

This might not be the best solution given this scenario.
Can you please suggest on any other efficient way of doing it so??

I sought in SO, but there were queries/replies on finding a single value occurring odd number of times but none like the one I have mentioned.

The relevance for this question is not known but seems to be asked in his interview...
Please suggest.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

If the values to be counted are bounded by even a moderately reasonable limit then you can just create an array of counters, and use the values to be counted as the array indices. You don't need a tight bound, and "reasonable" is somewhat a matter of platform. I would not hesitate to take this approach for a bound (and therefore array size) sufficient for all `uint16_t` values, and that's not a hard limit:

```
#define UPPER_BOUND 65536

uint64_t count[UPPER_BOUND];

void count_values(size_t num_values, uint16_t values[num_values]) {
    size_t i;

    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));
    for (i = 0; i < num_values; i += 1) {
        count[values[i]] += 1;
    )
}
```

Since you only need to track even vs. odd counts, though, you really only need one bit per distinct value in the input.  Squeezing it that far is a bit extreme, but this isn't so bad:

```
#define UPPER_BOUND 65536

uint8_t odd[UPPER_BOUND];

void count_values(size_t num_values, uint16_t values[num_values]) {
    size_t i;

    memset(odd, 0, sizeof(odd));
    for (i = 0; i < num_values; i += 1) {
        odd[values[i]] ^= 1;
    )
}
```

At the end, `odd[i]` contains `1` if the value `i` appeared an odd number of times, and it contains `0` if `i` appeared an even number of times.

On the other hand, if the values to be counted are so widely distributed that an array would require too much memory, then the hash table approach seems reasonable.  In that case, however, you are asking the wrong question.  Rather than

> how to decide on the size of the hash table?

you should be asking something along the lines of "what hash table implementation doesn't require me to manage the table size manually?"  There are several.  Personally, I have used [UTHash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) successfully, though as of recently it is no longer maintained.

You could also use a linked list maintained in order, or a search tree.  No doubt there are other viable choices.

You also asked

> Once the list is walked through & the hash table is populated (with the 'count' number of occurrences for each values/indices), only way to find/list the odd number of times occurring value is to walk through the table & find it out? Is that's the only way to do?

If you perform the analysis via the general approach we have discussed so far then yes, the only way to read out the result is to iterate through the counts.  I can imagine alternative, more complicated, approaches wherein you switch numbers between lists of those having even counts and those having odd counts, but I'm having trouble seeing how whatever efficiency you might gain in readout could fail to be swamped by the efficiency loss at the counting stage.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can walk the list and toggle the value's existence in a set. The resulting set will contain all of the values that appeared an odd number of times. However, this only works for that specific predicate, and the more generic count-then-filter algorithm you describe will be required if you wanted, say, all of the entries that appear an even number of times.

Both algorithms should be O(N) time and worst-case O(N) space, and the constants will *probably* be lower for the set-based algorithm, but you'll need to benchmark it against your data. In practice, I'd run with the more generic algorithm unless there was a clear performance problem.